SQL Server error de sintaxis con for
Me sale un error de sintaxis cerca del for y en el end for en mi SQL Server. ¿Por qué?
El código es este:
declare @valor int;

 FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
   set @valor = @valor +1
 END LOOP;

 select @valor as valor; 


Más allá de la respuesta correcta que ya recibiste, es importante evitar los bucles en SQL Server. ¿Qué es lo que tratas de hacer?

En SQL Server no se usa FOR. Cámbialo por un WHILE, así:
DECLARE @valor INT = 0;
DECLARE @i INT = 1;

WHILE @i <= 5
BEGIN
    SET @valor = @valor + 1;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END

SELECT @valor AS valor;

Esto hace lo mismo, pero con la sintaxis correcta.

Este error ocurre porque SQL Server no admite directamente la estructura FOR que son propias de otros sistemas de bases de datos como PL/SQL en Oracle.
SQL Server utiliza una sintaxis diferente para manejar bucles.
En SQL Server, puedes usar un bucle WHILE para lograr una funcionalidad similar.
DECLARE @Variable INT = 0;--Supongamos que esta es la variable a trabajar
DECLARE @contador INT = 1;--Tenemos que hacer uso de un contador, dependiendo de tus necesidades puede inicializarse en 1 o en 0

WHILE (@contador <= 3)--Colocamos la condición en la que se ejecutara el ciclo
BEGIN--Indicamos el inicio del ciclo
    SET @Variable = @Variable + 1;--Aquí iria la lógica de tu variable
    SET @contador = @contador + 1;--Agregamos un 1 al contador para avanzar el ciclo
END;--Indicamos el fin del ciclo

Espero te haya resultado útil.
